# Why do my doughnuts always deflate while frying?

Tags: doughnuts

[image: these are the doughnuts I made a few weeks ago didn't turn out so good.]I've had this problem for a while. My doughnuts never puff up well in the oil. They sink while frying, they don't have the white line around the edge,  feel hard, taste hard, and look crumbly like hard bread. They taste cooked, not doughy. The thing is, I properly proofed the doughnuts and always followed the recipe correctly, so I don't understand why they turn out this way.

Comment: Welcome! Have you checked your oil temperature? What’s your recipe? How do you determine that they are properly proofed? Do you have a photo of the failed ones? If you say that you had the problem for a while, have you ever made donuts that turned out well? If so, were there any major changes since then? Brand of flour, yeast or oil, a move to a different altitude? You can always [edit] your post to add more details.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.